# Dropbox to rename shared public folder without losing the current shared-URL

Tags: dropbox, rename, shared-folders

Somtimes after publishing the URL of the folder to many colleagues, I need to rename the folder - thoug doing that will break the link/url I have given to them.

So my need is to rename the folder, and still keeping the URL work with the new name. How can we archive it?

p.s.

My quick google search [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=dropbox%20how%20to%20rename%20without%20losing%20the%20shared%20public%20URL) not giving me any helpful hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox recently updated their software to allow for renaming of your shared folder without changing the shared URL. I got an e-mail about this but deleted it. :( I found a news article though stating this new change with [renaming shared folders](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/internet/news/dropbox-now-lets-you-rename-or-move-shared-files-without-breaking-links-836680) in May 2016.

[Dropbox Help about Renaming Shared Folders](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/64)